# Passing JWT in node js from backend to frontend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

How do I pass the value of JWT from my node js backend to android/ios frontend?
Should it be scored in my mongoDB database to be picked up each time by the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting your problem when user will login JWT is sent from the node backend and your android device will store it and for every request, it will send the JWT to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Typically for mobile apps, if you're trying to get a JWT from your node.js server, it is passed as a response to an API request.

One pattern if you're using JWT for authentication is the client will make a request to the node.js API at /authenticate for example, which will send back the JWT in the response body if authentication was successful. The client can then pass this token with subsequent requests to show that it has been authenticated- the server will parse the JWT to determine whether it is valid.

There's a great article on this here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens